# Why is linearity a requirement of a integral

Tags: integration, measure-theory, statistics, lebesgue-integral, stochastic-integrals

I was reading Philip Protter's Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations textbook. He mentions that an operator, $I_X$, induced by $X$ should be linear to be called an integral.

I have a basic understanding of integration concepts and I understand that Lebesgue integral can be proven to be linear. However, I was wondering what is the significance of linearity for integrals. Why did the author say that the operator should be linear to be called an integral. Is it simply because integration is an extension of sums, which is linear? Or is there a more rigorous mathematical reason behind it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: There won't be any rigorous mathematical reason for why the usage of an English word should be restricted. Your explanation is as good as any.

Comment: thanks for your reply, what I meant is that is linearity of integrals a result of linearity of summations? Or is there another explanation for the fact that all integrals are linear?

Comment: The whole catch is the word "integral". Our intuition from calculus says that "integral" should be some kind of analogue of "sum". Maybe not exactly "continuous sum", but still. But this isn't exactly a mathematical definition of the word "integral", it's an English usage. By contrast "Riemann integral", "Lebesgue integral", and "Ito integral" are all mathematically defined.

Comment: Historically, the concept of integral has been developed for solve three classical problems: (1) Integrals should be linear. (2) Integrals should interchange with limit symbols. (3) Integrals should satisfy some formulation like Fundamental Theorem. These are the reasons why all books about integrals (stochastic integrals, Riemman, Lebesgue, Orlikz, HK) always are centered in this problems

Comment: Thank you both for the insights. Based on sinbadh's reply, I guess I can better phrase my question. My confusion revolves around his point number 1. Why exactly do we require integrals to be linear. From Ian's reply, different types of integrals are defined differently in mathematical terms (Riemann, Lebesgue, and etc), and each type can be proven to satisfy linearity using different methods. However, sinbadh's point 1 sounds like regardless of mathematical construction of the integral, it is required to be linear. I dont understand why this is. Or am I completely missing something here.Thanks